# Executing Child packages without using master package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have many Fact and Dimension packages which are executed using vb script . Today one of my seniors proposed that these packages should be executed individually instead of creating a master package to execute the child pkgs using execute package task .His reasoning was based on the fact that execute package task will create several threads which will be performance intensive when compared to individually executing the packages.

Leaving aside sharing of config file and other issue how can individually executing it be more performant that creating master package for all the child packages?

By the way the child packages are executed out of process which is configured in the Execute Package Task

Comment: The short answer is "try it and see for yourself". But it isn't clear what problem your senior is trying to solve, is your current master package solution running too slowly, or using too much CPU or RAM, or what is his concern exactly? And although it isn't really clear from your question how you would execute them, running them individually one after another could be slower than running them in parallel. But the best answer to performance questions is always "don't guess, measure it".

Comment: When executing the child packages out of process ,i can see different dtshost.exe making the master package run very slow as it is consuming lot of memory .More over i cannot use in Process as i want the master package to run even if the child package fails. Moreover the packages are executed sequentially and these are executed using VB script one at a time

Answer (score 1):

I use the following as the guideline:

If you are simply using many packages to structure your solution in a more modular fashion, executing in-process is probably the way to go because you don't have the overhead of launching more processes. I'm happy to pass on that advice here.

Quoted from: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/05/16/1414.aspx

Comment: As per my understanding using In process execution i cannot continue the execution of master package even if the child package fails

Answer (score 1):

No performance solution should be applied without taking metrics before and after.

It sounds like this is a stab in the dark - I don't see any metrics about how long each of the packages take to perform and what kind of CPU and I/O usage is going on.

Is he essentially saying they should be executed sequentially instead of parallel? You don't need to throw away your master package design to do that.